Why do I get this error when I try to use react-pdf in my next js 14.2
I've been having a problem with react-pdf in my next js, i've been following multiple tutorial and it seems like still have an error.
I get this error
  ⨯ Instead change the require of react-pdf.js in C:\Users\TCET
 ADMIN\Desktop\next\.next\server\app\(client)\page.js to a dynamic
 import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
     at @react-pdf/renderer (C:\Users\TCET ADMIN\Desktop\next\.next\server\app\(client)\page.js:110:18)
     at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\TCET ADMIN\Desktop\next\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
     at eval (_components/CreateAppointmentPdf.tsx:7:77)
     at (ssr)/./app/(client)/_components/CreateAppointmentPdf.tsx (C:\Users\TCET
 ADMIN\Desktop\next\.next\server\app\(client)\page.js:419:1)
     at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\TCET ADMIN\Desktop\next\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
     at eval (_components/downloadbutton.tsx:10:79)
     at (ssr)/./app/(client)/_components/downloadbutton.tsx (C:\Users\TCET
 ADMIN\Desktop\next\.next\server\app\(client)\page.js:463:1)
     at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\TCET ADMIN\Desktop\next\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
     at eval (_components/create-schedule-dialog.tsx:38:74)
     at (ssr)/./app/(client)/_components/create-schedule-dialog.tsx (C:\Users\TCET
 ADMIN\Desktop\next\.next\server\app\(client)\page.js:452:1)
     at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\TCET ADMIN\Desktop\next\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
     at eval (_components/left-calendar.tsx:10:81)
     at (ssr)/./app/(client)/_components/left-calendar.tsx (C:\Users\TCET
 ADMIN\Desktop\next\.next\server\app\(client)\page.js:496:1)
     at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\TCET ADMIN\Desktop\next\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
     at eval (page.tsx:9:83)
     at (ssr)/./app/(client)/page.tsx (C:\Users\TCET ADMIN\Desktop\next\.next\server\app\(client)\page.js:540:1)
     at Object.__webpack_require__ [as require] (C:\Users\TCET ADMIN\Desktop\next\.next\server\webpack-runtime.js:33:43)
     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>) digest: "2904845551"


I tried multiple tutorial, and I tried it to make it like this. I created a custom components and I just pass on different props on it.
MainComponent.tsx
   <DownloadButton
       disabledButton={!confirmAgreement}
       onClick={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
       isPending={isPending}
       form={form} />
     </DialogClose>

DownloadButton.tsx
'use client'
import React from 'react'
import CreateDocumentPDF from './CreateAppointmentPdf'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DownloadButton = ({ form, onClick, disabledButton, isPending }: any) => {
    const [isClient, setIsClient] = useState(false)

    const PDFDownloadLink = dynamic(
        () => import("@react-pdf/renderer").then((mod) => mod.PDFDownloadLink),
        {
          ssr: false,
          loading: () => <p>Loading...</p>,
        }
      );

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsClient(true)
    }, [])

    return (
        <PDFDownloadLink
            fileName='Appointment'
            document={
                <CreateDocumentPDF form={form} />
            }
        >
            <Button>
                    
            </Button>
        </PDFDownloadLink>
    )
}

export default DownloadButton

And then this my CreateAppointmendPDF.tsx. The problem here is when I use the feature coming from @react-pdf/renderer. I get the error.
import { Document, Font, Page, Text, View } from '@react-pdf/renderer'

const CreateDocumentPDF = ({
    form
}: any) => {
    return (
        <Document>

        </Document>
    )
}

export default CreateDocumentPDF


the full error really starts like ⨯ Instead change the require of .... etc? what is this odd ⨯?

@Stykgwar Try adding 'use client' in CreateDocumentPDF.

I did this and still having the same error

Version 4.0.0 of @react-pdf/renderer appears to have dropped support for CommonJS modules completely. :-/
You'll have to either downgrade to @react-pdf/renderer version 3.4.5 or upgrade your TS compiler settings to output esmodules.
i.e., change your tsconfig.json settings to specify:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6" // or "esnext", "es2020", "es2022", etc.
  }
}

See here for details on the "module" TS option.
I had the same issue, and was getting more issues by switching my output settings. I could not get things resolved; so, I downgraded to 3.4.5. Hopefully they provide cjs exports again in a future version..
EDIT:
Sadly this is a permanent decision by the authors:
https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/2907

Saved my day thank you!

You need to update your next.config.js file. Add the changes below:
const nextConfig = {
      experimental: {
      serverComponentsExternalPackages: ['@react-pdf/renderer'],
    }
 };

For more information check this NextJS Docs and React-pdf docs.

Not solved my problem without downgrade package version to 3.4.5 and adding compiler options to module es6

You can import PDFDownloadLink from @react-pdf/renderer like:
import { PDFDownloadLink, PDFViewer } from "@react-pdf/renderer";

Since Next.js uses Server-Side Rendering (SSR) and @react-pdf/renderer is designed for the browser environment, you should use a dynamic import with ssr: false to import components that rely on @react-pdf/renderer :
In the DownloadButton.tsx component, you import PDFDownloadLink normally:
import { PDFDownloadLink } from "@react-pdf/renderer";

Then, in your MainComponent.tsx where you use DownloadButton.tsx, you can apply a dynamic import:
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const DownloadButton = dynamic(
  () => import('./DownloadButton'),
  { ssr: false }
);

export default function MainComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <DownloadButton />
    </div>
  );
}

This way, DownloadButton.tsx will work on the client side, as required by the @react-pdf/renderer components.
